# LLDB equivalent to GDB's 'set auto-solib-add on'

Tags: lldb

I'm trying to remote debug a dynamically loaded shared object (via dlopen) with the LLDB/LLDB Server.
I have noticed that the debug symbols are not automatically loaded in this case.

When using the GDB for similar purposes I have used the 'set auto-solib-add on' configuration to instruct the GDB that new loaded shared objects and their symbols will be automatically added/loaded.

Is there some equivalent option for the LLDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lldb has no `set auto-solib-add off`, this behavior is always on.  You can use the lldb command `image list <my_dylib_name.dylib>` to see whether lldb was notified of the image being loaded by dyld.  The mechanism that informs lldb about shared library loads is pretty straight-forward, I would be surprised if we weren't told about the library loading.  The various mechanisms to get from a dylib to its debug information are more complex, most likely there's something going wrong there.

Comment: It seems there is a problem in loading the debug symbols.I'm not sure how to do something similar like the gdb commands `set debug-file-directory` and `set solib-search-path`

Comment: There's a page on the lldb site: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/symbols.html describing how debug symbols are handled on macOS.  That might help.

Comment: The remaining lines tell LLDB where to go to find the symbols for debugging.
`settings set target.inline-breakpoint-strategy always
settings append target.exec-search-paths <PATH>/objdir-android-opt/toolkit/library/build`
`settings append target.exec-search-paths <PATH>/objdir-android-opt/mozglue/build `[see here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/contributor/native-debugging.html)


Also found an interesting script to generate lldb init file with solib search paths [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/scripts/gdbclient.py).